# Golang png draw transparent

Tags: image, go

I am trying to draw multiple transparent images to form a big one and save it as PNG

```
func generateUserImage(username string, items []models.Item) error {
    imageFile, err := os.Create("public/items/users/" + username + ".png")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    profileImage := image.NewRGBA(image.Rect(0, 0, 261, 336))
    for _, item := range items {
        revel.INFO.Println(item)
        itemFile, err := os.Open("public/items/universe/" + item.Type + "/" + item.Name + ".png")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        itemImage, err := png.Decode(itemFile)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        draw.Draw(profileImage, profileImage.Bounds(), itemImage, image.Point{0, 0}, draw.Src)
        itemFile.Close()
    }
    err = png.Encode(imageFile, profileImage)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer imageFile.Close()
    return nil
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine except that the final image will only contain the LAST image of the range loop (even tho the range loops 5 times). All images are .png and with transparent background. Here is a demo on how images look

[image]

You can try to save the image and see that the background is transparent... So I have no idea why the final image only contains 1 image and not all

Thanks

Comment: Use `draw.Over` rather than `draw.Src`?

Comment: Forgot about that. That solved it!

Comment: Fyi, you're deferring a close as your second to last line in the function. Defer it after you check the error of the function that returns that. So in your example, defer the close just before the line that has the variable, profileImage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments.

```
draw.Draw(profileImage, profileImage.Bounds(), itemImage, image.Point{0, 0}, draw.Over)
```